# Nuxt Content: How to render the markdown content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown, nuxt-content

everyone. I'm a bit confused when following the documentation.

Given I have a markdown file:

```
 /content/article/design.md
---
title: How to design
year: 2023
---
The content of this markdown
```

```
In my /pages/article/[...slug].vue 

<template>
  <main>
    <ContentDoc>
      <template #default="{ doc }">
        <p>{{ doc.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ doc.year }}</p>
        <ContentRenderer :value="doc"/>
      </template>
    </ContentDoc>
  </main>
</template>
```

Problem: The title and year is rendered. But they don't return anything.
Question: What component can I use to render the content from the markdown?

Comment: Where did you fetch the data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand what or where `doc` comes from without seeing the relevant `<script>` code.  Similarly, how are you attempting to export/share the title/year values from the markdown file within your vue component? Also, how do you determine that something is rendered but at the same time say they don't "return anything"? What does that mean? ...Please, share all **relevant** code

Comment: @yoduh `doc` is a specific usage of the `nuxt/content` module, and it does not need to be declared in the `<script>` tag. However, I have tried his code, and it works, so I'm not sure why he is having problems. He should provide more information.

Comment: @EricChang, I found having Nuxt Layout somehow messes up with this. I've started over and removed all the layouts, and this works just fine. I'll provide more information soon.